How can I parse / deserialise idp metadata using opensaml
I want to parse idp metadata using opensaml as depicted on multiple platforms that it is the most reliable lib for implementing SSO authentication, As a newbie I am not able to get the reliable resource, I tried libraries like onelogin and others, but please help me start with parsing of IDP metadata using opensaml library
